Как запустить окно одновременно с программой?
Хочу использовать маленькое окно в качестве индикатора работы программы. Т. е. чтобы при запуске программы появилось небольшое окно и после окончания работы программы оно исчезло.
Нигде не могу найти описание того, как это сделать. Везде описывается как сделать обработку событий в окне (нажатий кнопок и т. п.).
Мне не надо, чтобы окно обрабатывало какие-либо события, а нужно, чтобы окно работало как индикатор: программа работает — появилось окно, программа закрылась — окно исчезло.
Как это сделать?

Вам надо чтобы окно обрабатывало события (в первую очередь событие перерисовки), иначе система посчитает окно зависшим и убьёт программу

И как это сделать?

Точно так же, как "везде описывается", просто не создавайте ненужную вам кнопку да и всё

А по какому событию будет запускаться основной скрипт?

Так наоборот основной скрипт должен запускать окно, не?

Почему бы не поместить иконку в трей? Пока программа будет работать, в трее будет висеть иконка. Как только скрипт завершит свою работу, иконку можно будет из трея убрать, тем самым сигнализируя о том, что ваша программа завершила свою работу.

pip install Pillow
pip install pystray

import threading
from PIL import Image
import pystray
import time

def create_icon():
    icon_image = Image.open(r"C:\Users\Amgarak\Desktop\PirateCaptain.ico")
    return pystray.Icon("PirateCaptain", icon_image)

def show_tray_image(icon):
    icon.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    icon = create_icon()  
    tray_thread = threading.Thread(target=show_tray_image, args=(icon,))
    tray_thread.start() 

    # Основной код делает что-то полезное
    for i in range(10): 
        print(i) 
        time.sleep(0.5)
    
    icon.stop()  # Чтото полезное сделали? Останавливаем иконку, программа завершается
    tray_thread.join()

P.S. pystray Package Documentation

Сделал с использованием этого кода. Все работает. Но! Когда сделал exe файл с помощью auto-py-to-exe, то при его запуске получил сообщение "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pystray'". Пересобрал файл с помощью pyinstaller. Файл запускается и работает, но запускается он в течении 3-4 сек. Хотя файл .py запускается мгновенно. Как это исправить?

Естественно pip install pystray я сделал.

@winkot Я предлагаю вам создать новый вопрос, где вы сможете более детально рассказать о проблемах с pyinstaller.

Документация pystray говорит, что он обязан запускаться в основном потоке. Подозреваю, что ваш код не заработает в macOS (даже если не обращать внимания на виндовый путь к иконке)

@andreymal в macOS не тестировал, так что тут прокомментировать не могу. На winOS работает. Я конечно не спорю, что лучше все GUI пускать в основном потоке, но в данном случае под win так реализовать было проще всего.
